# error while connecting to hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to make a remote connection to HBase configured in not distributed mode.
My code is the following in java playframework:

```
    // Instantiating a configuration class
    Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    try {
        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(hbaseConfiguration);
        newConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "77.154.69.181");
        newConfig.set("hbase.zookeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        HConnection connection = HConnectionManager
                .getConnection(newConfig);
       HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(connection);
        if (!hBaseAdmin.isMasterRunning())
            throw new Exception("Hbase is not running");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
    [error] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 10000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=vm-77446.localdomain/77.154.69.181:37027]
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1485)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1505)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1711)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:876)
[error]     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.isMasterRunning(HBaseAdmin.java:271)
[error]     at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:29)
[error]     at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:95)
[error]     at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:95)
[error]     at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
[error]     at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:70)
[error]     at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
[error]     at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
[error]     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
[error]     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)
[error]     at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
[error]     at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[error]     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
[error]     at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
[error]     at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: I suggest adding language-based tags to your question for proper exposure and syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1):

```
    newConfig.set("hbase.zookeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

should be

```
    newConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

you have a typo in your code.

Answer (score 1):

From this "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException", Your hbase master(HMaster) is not running. Try to open http://MasterIp:60010 from a browser and check your master is really running(Hbase master page with the table names should be listed).

If master is running, then add

```
    newConfig.set("hbase.master","MasterIP:60000");
```

right below

```
   newConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
[error] Mon Oct 12 09:33:07 GMT+01:00 2015, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68345: row 'Sample2,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=vm-77446.localdomain,40953,1444404662326, seqNum=0
[error] 
[error]  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:264)
[error]

Comment: Canyou try to open http://MasterIp:60010 in browser. Replace MasterIp with your master hostname or IP.

You need to make sure your Hbase is working fine by using hbase hbck.

Comment: I have solved the problem by opening range port on the server because HBase was always responding in differents ports.